# Preview PDF in Mailer

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

I have some old code where I create PDF files from a .xib. When I email the PDF file generated from the xib I can get a preview of the PDF in the mail window.

With this code below, I can generate a single PDF file from a group a PDF's and I can email it, but won't show the preview of the PDF page, which is what Im trying to achieve.

I can't find anything in the documentation about this. Is there a way to display a preview of the PDF that Im sending?

I don't want to preview the PDF in a web view, the preview should be in mail view controller once it's presented. I can preview in the mail view controller with PDF files but that features (for some reason) stopped working with the block of code I wrote.

```
    //wrap all PDF files together into one PDF file
    //*************************************************************


    NSArray     *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString    *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString    *oldFilePath=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPDF.pdf"];
    NSURL       *oldFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:oldFilePath];

    CGContextRef context = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL((__bridge_retained CFURLRef)oldFileUrl, NULL, NULL);


    for (OBJreport in pages)
    {

        // Get the first page from each source document
        NSString            *pdfPath        = OBJreport.rep_filePath;
        NSURL               *pdfUrl         = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath];
        CGPDFDocumentRef    pdfDoc          = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge_retained CFURLRef)pdfUrl);
        CGPDFPageRef        pdfPage         = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfDoc, 1);
        CGRect              pdfCropBoxRect  = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pdfPage, kCGPDFMediaBox);

        // Copy the page to the new document
        CGContextBeginPage(context, &pdfCropBoxRect);
        CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, pdfPage);

        // Close the source files
        CGContextEndPage(context);
        CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdfDoc);
    }


    // Cleanup
    //*************************************************************
    CGContextRelease(context);


    //add the final output file to the pages array for cleanup
    //*************************************************************
    OBJ_report *cleanUpOBJreport = [OBJ_report new];


    cleanUpOBJreport.rep_filePath   = [oldFileUrl path];
    cleanUpOBJreport.rep_mimiType   = @"application/pdf";
    cleanUpOBJreport.rep_data       = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:oldFileUrl];
    cleanUpOBJreport.rep_fileName   = @"myPDF.pdf";

    [pages addObject:cleanUpOBJreport];




    //mail
    //*************************************************************

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    [mailer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    [mailer setSubject:@"File Attached"];
    [mailer setMessageBody:defaultEmailCoverLetter isHTML:NO];

    //add all pages
    [mailer addAttachmentData:cleanUpOBJreport.rep_data mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"myPDF.pdf"];
    [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];


    //cleanup files
    //*************************************************************
    OBJ_report *clean_OBJreport = [OBJ_report new];
    for (clean_OBJreport in pages)
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:clean_OBJreport.rep_filePath error:&error];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to show the preview of a PDF. You just need to add a `UIWebView` to your view and let it load the PDF preview for you.

In your case, lets say you have added a `UIWebView` to your `mailer` view controller's view (or preferably to any other view) and connected that to a outlet property `previewerWebview` in the view controller. It seems from your code that your PDF file is being generated at the url pointed by `oldFileUrl` variable in your class. So you can load a preview of the PDF with two simple lines of code:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:oldFileUrl];
[self.previewerWebview loadRequest:request];
```

And that should display the preview of your generated PDF in place.

Comment: I don't want to preview the PDF in a web view, the preview should be in mail view controller once it's presented. I can preview in the mail view controller with PDF files but that features (for some reason) stopped working with the block of code I wrote.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your mail view controller. If this is a custom view controller derived from `UIViewConttroller`, you can always add `UIWebView` to its view and let it work as the previewer. And if you already have a tailor-made but non-functional previewer there, why dont you share its code so that we can decide why its not working?

Comment: I mean the default view that is presented upon calling [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];thanks for helping.

Comment: Thats where I'm trying to point you to. your `mailer` VC is loaded from some xib and you can readily add a web view in that and let it act as the previewer.

Comment: Your right I guess, but it does not answer the question of why the code "broke" in the first place. Because before I combined the PDF files together into one, I could preview in the VC without doing any additional code. What confuses me is I can't preview the PDF file in the VC, it stopped working, it just show up as a file icon (which is a good file), but it just won't preview.

Comment: You answer is a worthy solution but I cant mark it as answered because I want to know why the code is broken.

Comment: It's not possible to say that until I know what's happening inside `MFMailComposeViewController` class. However, I found that you are deleting the PDF file after presenting the `MFMailComposeViewController` VC and it wont display anything if it tries to read the PDF from the same path to generate the preview.

Comment: Only default actions are happening in the mail VC. Even though it is deleted, it should still show. My other block of code with the PDFs still in single sheet will preview ok, even with deleting the original files right after calling present mail VC. Mail, must be taking instances of all objects/resources its needs to send mail with the VC... so thats not the issue. Also I tested the code without the delete command and it still won't work.

Comment: Subviews cannot be added to MFMailComposeViewController.

Answer (score 0):

PDF's, when more then one page, will show as an icon rather then previewing the entire document. This is the default behaviour.